# How to iterate array of array using jquery

Tags: jquery

My array:-

```
var data = [
    [4, "Shailesh ", "Sharma"],
    [5, "Devesh Kumar ", "Neema"],
    [6, "Vardan S ", "Khanna"],
    [208, "Kamlesh ", "Lohiya"],
    [210, "Raj Bahadur ", "Singh"]
]
```

Comment: Hi @parth welcome to SO :-)  Can you please add what code you have already tried yourself to do this? At SO we are here to help with code you already have.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do this using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) like:

```
var data = [
    [4, "Shailesh ", "Sharma"],
    [5, "Devesh Kumar ", "Neema"],
    [6, "Vardan S ", "Khanna"],
    [208, "Kamlesh ", "Lohiya"],
    [210, "Raj Bahadur ", "Singh"]
]

$.each(data, function (i, n) {
    $.each(n, function (i2, n2) {
        console.log(i2, n2);
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

*For adding as option getting data from array*

```
var option = '';
$.each(data, function (i, n) {
    option += '<option value="' + n[0] + '">' + n[1] + '</option>';
});
console.log(option);
$('select').append(option);
```

Comment: this is giving me a single single character. i need whole value between double quotes.

Comment: @parthbhorania: can provide an example of your expected result?

Comment: i am gonna use this value in "<select><option value="4">shailesh</option><option value="5">Davesh Kumar</option></select>" .

Comment: @parthbhorania: That's simple. You can do like in the updated code above. Hope you can take from here. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [[4,"Shailesh ","Sharma"],[5,"Devesh Kumar ","Neema"],[6,"Vardan S ","Khanna"],[208,"Kamlesh ","Lohiya"],[210,"Raj Bahadur ","Singh"]]

for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++)
{
  for(var j=0; j<a[i].length;j++){
  console.log("value:"+a[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct - but doesn't use JQuery :-)

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript:

```
var data = [
  [4, "Shailesh ", "Sharma"],
  [5, "Devesh Kumar ", "Neema"],
  [6, "Vardan S ", "Khanna"],
  [208, "Kamlesh ", "Lohiya"],
  [210, "Raj Bahadur ", "Singh"]
];

data.forEach(function (a) {
  console.log(a[0] + a[1] + a[2]);
});
```

I can't really see a good reason to do it in jQuery.